# How to create nine-patch and use it in my App?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I want to create a nine-patch image and use that in my App but I don't know how to create it?

I've searched through the Android source code on the Web and I can't seem to find any examples of this. I need a tutorial so that I can understand the process.

Comment: Have a look at the doc [how to create .9.png](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) and [nine png images](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

Comment: These links may help you : http://www.androiddom.com/2011/05/android-9-patch-image-tutorial.html and http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Android-9-Patch-Scaled-Png-Image-Guide/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a tool included in the android sdk to create and test nine patch images:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

You can also create a nine patch file using every gfx package out there ( photoshop, paint.net, ... ) using the creation guideline here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Answer (score 23):

I have searched the **best and the simplest answer** to make 9-patch image. Now to make the 9 patch image is the easiest task.

From [HERE](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html) you can make a 9-patch image for all the resolutions - XHDPI,HDPI,MDPI,LDPI in just one click.

Let me know if you have any queries, and do upvote it, if it was helpful to you.[image]

Comment: Other Links are also useful in this link

Comment: Can't set more than 1 vertical area for stretching

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 20):

I just found that awesome alternative 9patch editor (by [Mikle Garin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/909085/mikle-garin)) and I think it 1000% better than standard one built in sdk:

[Editor JAR download link](http://weblookandfeel.com/downloads/preview/NinePatchEditor.jar)
[Editor source code](http://weblookandfeel.com/downloads/preview/Sources.zip)
[Editor official page](http://weblookandfeel.com/nine-patch-editor/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the kind words about my app! :)
I am working on updating the editor application and will upload it on the WebLaF site. Some more features (like multi-images editing) are coming there. Plus there is already newer version than the one you have posted on screenshot with some useful features added aswell.

Comment: this is a beautiful tool

Answer (score 5):

I've created a tool that allows automatically create 9-patch images from regular PNG images for simple cases where stretchable areas are 1 pixel wide. Here's sample input and output (showed at 400%):

[image: input] [image: output 400%]

[Project page on github](https://github.com/grassator/rain)

Answer (score 3):

A NinePatch image is a standard PNG image created with Photoshop, Illustrator, Paint... etc. 
To add a NinePatch rule to it, just drag/drop it on the draw9patch.bat tool in your Android SDK directory.

**IF** you don't use the draw9patch.bat tool, you must include an extra **1px** transparent  border to draw the NinePatch rules with a **1px black** (#000000) pencil size before you save it.

**Important!!!** Save the image with the extension **myimage.9.png** as a transparent PNG-8/PNG-24.

[Image: Explanation of NinePatch graphic rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVnws.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html 

Although android provides the tool for ninepatch images .Open terminal and go to android sdk -tools path and type ./draw9patch. But this is the best link you can make for all density in just one click.
```