# Android Studio doesn't recognize 9patch images in drawables

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable, nine-patch

I have a nine patch image and gave it a name like this:

> img.9.png

When I import it into **drawable-hdpi** or **drawable-xhdpi** folders and so on android studio is unable to recognize image and gives me an error :

> Couldn't resolve resource @mipmap/img.9
> Failed to convert @mipmap/img.9 into a drawable
>
> Error:(69, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at
> 'background' with value '@drawable/img').

Also when I import this 9patch image into **drawable** folder android studio displays it correctly but when I build and run application give an error:

> Error:(69, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at
> 'background' with value '@mipmap/img.9').

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793099/how-to-create-nine-patch-and-use-it-in-my-app

Comment: my 9patch images work correctly when i use draw9patch-tools of Android SDK it work completely correct but android studio doesn't recognize and give error

Comment: Clean and rebuild then restart your studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501334/add-9-patch-image-to-android-studio

Comment: I clean it over and over :| doesn't work!

Answer (score 7):

The extension must be **.9.png** but you don't have to include **.9** in your reference!
So, it's not `@mipmap/img.9`, but `@mipmap/img`

Moreover, `mipmap` shoul only be used for the launcher icon, not for the graphic resources.

Comment: I overlook this .Good observation sir

Comment: yeah I know that the extension must be without .9 but android studio show  img.9 when I pick up it

Comment: I set image path manually , android:background="@drawable/img" , but still android studio give error:: Error:(69, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/img').

Comment: And did you move the image into the `drawable` folder?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this? Same problem for me. I downloaded these png's from google. [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/images/signin-assets.zip). Android Studio Version 1.5 Preview 2

Comment: It's not Android Studio issue, it's gradle problem, because I build using command line, and get the same error